# How to notify specific user after button click

Tags: java, android, notifications

Het everyone, I'm currently trying to send the user a message after a diffrent user has accepted their request. (Android Java). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are use api in applications then three scenarios build like.

1. By API
   After accepting request you can hit an api and save value that user A accept user B friendship request. On user B side  you can show that when it's check my request is accepted or not.
2. By API with broadcast receiver
   After accepting request you can hit an api and save value that user A accept user B friendship request. After that make notification for  user B.
   When user B get notifications then  you can show that when it's check my request is accepted by broadcast receiver.
3. By Socket
   I think it's will be simple and easy and productive.
   Use Socket based library like socket.io etc. You can easily hit emit, and listener, for changing data (accepted or not).Build with backend also. It's make realtime reflection also.